# Chrome dev channel features list

Tags: google-chrome

where can I find list of features either completed or in development in Chrome developer channel?

I'am pretty sure, that I've come across such a list before and can't find it again after spending an hour searching.

I've looked at http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel but could not find a related link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the link finally. It seems they have changed the location.

http://www.chromestatus.com/features